# how to add RMSE to a premade estimator

Tags: tensorflow-estimator

I have been struggling with efficiently adding RMSE output for my premade estimator model like you get when using keras' train function. I was eyeing with using add_metrics, but I am not even sure if you can use it for premade estimators and if yes how? Meaning how do I need to code the metric_fn?

The way google uses via calling predict and transforming this into a np.array takes ages for me.

I am happy receiving any idea on how to make this work.

Thanks in advance!